# Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError - Java heap space - Neo4j - Cypher

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I loaded data (2.8 M) records using the LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS

When I try to create relationships using the following script in Cypher, I get the following error -Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError - Java heap space
I also created an index to speed up the relationship process.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Entity(ENT_ID)

PROFILE
MATCH(Entity)
MATCH (a:Entity {ENT_ID : Entity.ENT_ID})
WITH Entity, a
MATCH (b:Entity {ENT_ID : Entity.PARENTID})
WITH a,b
MERGE (a)-[r:RELATION]->(b)
RETURN r
```

I have already gone through the other links who had faced the same issue, but did not find the solution to the same. Hence I am reposting this question. My dataset has 2 columns ENT_ID and PARENTID. I am trying to create the relationship using the above query.

I have no background knowledge of Java or Java Virtual Machine. Just based on other links, I thought I would have the error would get wiped out by using the below properties:

neo4j.conf:

```
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=3g
```

-- Initial Java Heap Size (in MB) :

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=1024
```

-- Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB) :

```
wrapper.java.maxmemory=16000
```

-- other beneficial settings that should boost performance :

```
wrapper.java.additional.6=-d64
wrapper.java.additional.7=-server
wrapper.java.additional.8=-Xss1024k
```

JAVA VM Tuning:

```
 -Xmx4000M
 -Xms4000M 
 -Xmn1000M
```

I'd appreciate any help

EDIT:

Based on the comment below: I used the following Query: It still throws me the same Java Heap Space:

```
PROFILE
MATCH (a:Entity)
WHERE a.PARENTID IS NOT NULL
WITH a
MATCH (b:Entity {ENT_ID : a.PARENTID})
MERGE (a)-[r:RELATION]->(b)
```

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: issue is in your CYPHER query because `MATCH(Entity)` also match all other nodes attached with `Entity`. 
Replace it with 
`MATCH (en:Entity) WITH en`
right now in your  case it is making cartesian product and Neo4j server become unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

As Usman commented, the `MATCH(Entity)` line is useless, and worse, it's matching against every node in your db, not just :Entity nodes, and causing a cartesian product.

I think what you want is something like this, processing all :Entity with a parentid, and making a RELATION from them to their parent:

```
PROFILE
MATCH (a:Entity)
WHERE a.PARENTID IS NOT NULL
WITH a
MATCH (b:Entity {ENT_ID : a.PARENTID})
MERGE (a)-[r:RELATION]->(b)
```

This should avoid the cartesian product, and be complexity n where n is the number of :Entity nodes.

I removed the RETURN as you probably do not want to return millions of relationships. Afterwards, if you want a count of those relationships, though, you can use:

```
MATCH (:Entity)-[r:Relation]->(:Entity)
RETURN COUNT(r)
```

Comment: Hey, Sorry for the late response. But I still get the same error. Java Heap Space. Thanks a lot for taking your time to try and help me

Comment: Just as a (late) followup, you can process this type of operation in batches to avoid blowing up your heap space. You can use [apoc.periodic.iterate()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#commit-batching) from APOC Procedures, matching to `a` from the query and returning it, and handling the match to `b` and subsequent MERGE of the relationship within the inner query, which will be executed per batch.